# Need for change size of meteor collection _id

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-collections

As we know .. Meteor collection after insert return a 16 char id, and that is too much for me.
Can i change meteor collection _id generation to generate a 6 char id instead of 16 char ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can roll send your own `_id` with the `insert` and as long as it is unique, Mongo will accept:

`Mongo.insert({_id:'foobar'})`

So when you go to `insert`, just generate a random 6 digit string. You'll have to do your own checking to verify your generated `_id` is unique.

Comment: Thanks .. that helped me :)